# Remove SUM column in SQL result

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT sum(number1), sum(number2),
CASE
  WHEN SUM(number1) % 2 = 1 THEN MIN(number1)
  ELSE MAX(number1)
END AS number1,
CASE
  WHEN SUM(number2) % 2 = 1 THEN MIN(number2)
  ELSE MAX(number2)
END AS number2
FROM numbers
```

The code above is returning the correct numbers, however there's an extra column that's showin.

Any ideas how?

Output is something like this:

```
sum | number1 | number2 |
123 |    1    |   2     |
```

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK9ZO.png)

My goal is if the SUM of number1 is an odd number then I will display the MIN number in number1 ELSE MAX number 1, same goes with number2. But I only need to display 2 columns(number1 and number2)

I would like to know on why **sum column is showing and how to remove it.**

Appreciate any kind of output!

Comment: The SELECT you included produces four columns, not the three you've indicated, so either the SQL is not real or the output is not real. In either case, if you include `SUM(number1)` in your SELECT, it's going to output that column. If you don't want the column output, then remove it from the column list that follows SELECT.

Comment: @KenWhite appreciate your response. If I removed it from SELECT then I can't use `sum(number1)` in my Case statement.

Comment: Holy moly! That's it can you post I'm new so I did not know that it's possible. Appreciate your help! Can you post an answer so I can mark it as best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every column after the `SELECT` will appear in your results. If you don't want them to appear, then don't include them in the list.

In the SQL you've posted, you can just remove the first two columns in the list, leaving only the two `CASE` statements.

```
SELECT 
CASE
  WHEN SUM(number1) % 2 = 1 THEN MIN(number1)
  ELSE MAX(number1)
END AS number1,
CASE
  WHEN SUM(number2) % 2 = 1 THEN MIN(number2)
  ELSE MAX(number2)
END AS number2
FROM numbers
```